# Android invalidate doesn't show intermediate animation

Tags: android, android-canvas

This is my code.
On swipe to the top is performed:

```
           for(int it = 0;it<4;it++){
                myBoard.step_up();

                invalidate();
            }       

            int ad = myBoard.merge_up();
            invalidate();
            for(int it = 0;it<4;it++){
                myBoard.step_up();
                invalidate();
            }
```

step_up and merge_up methods change the values of myBoard. The onDraw method draws the screen according to the myBoard values. But i **do not see** intermediate results of movements! Just start postition and then end position, the same as in the following code:

```
           for(int it = 0;it<4;it++){
                myBoard.step_up();
            }       

            int ad = myBoard.merge_up();
            for(int it = 0;it<4;it++){
                myBoard.step_up();
            }   
                invalidate();
```

How to deal this problem? It is very important for me

Update:
The code from onCreate:

```
   GraphicsView myview=new GraphicsView(this);
   setContentView(myview);
```

GraphicsView entire code is too big. The part of it:

```
  public GraphicsView(Context context) { super(context); 

  this.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(getApplicationContext()) {

  public void onSwipeTop() {
                  //above code
  }
                 //other methods
  }
  protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
  {
             //draw
  }
  }
```

Comment: Can you post a little more code where you are setting the layout of your file? Specifically, are you setting int using setContentView() or creating it in context?

Comment: Hey can you please post some more code or even the class itself ?